# Calling methods based on parameters in Java

Tags: java, methods

I don't know how exactly to word this, but I will give it a shot.

I want to call a method based on a parameter. I'm not sure if this is possible but I surely hope it is because it would save about 200 lines of code and a hassle! Please let me know if I need to be more specific about anything!

```
public static void example(String a){
        System.(a).println("Hello")
   }

public static void main(String[] args){
        example("out");
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could be more specific about these "200 lines". `System.out` is only one line

Comment: @markspace This isn't overloading. OP wants to call `System.out` given the string `"out"`

Comment: Oh I saw `String` and `String[]` and assumed it was a question about overloading.  Mea culpa.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference`System.out` with `"out"` (or other possible fields)  [using Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string) but you'd ultimately end up *adding more code* for exception handling, not saving much.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible, you will get the compile-time error below.

***Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method example(String) from the type***

Here (example) is in the non-static area & main method is static.

Answer (score -1):

try something like this

```
public void example(String a){
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("java.lang.system");
    Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod(a, parameterTypes);
    method.invoke(objectToInvokeOn, params);
   }

public static void main(String[] args){
        example("out");
    }
```

- parameterTypes is of type Class[] and declares the parameters the
  method takes
- params is of type Object[] and declares the parameters
  to be passed to the method

Comment: This won't work, because `System.out` is not a method.